# Which of the following statement is true regarding the set $A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ be a continuous function and $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ be dfined by $$A = \{ y \in \mathbb R : y = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) \text{ for some sequence }x_n \to + \infty \}$$

Then the set  $A$ is necessarily

1. $A$ is connected set
2. $A$ is compact.
3. $A$ is a singelton set.
4. None of the above.

if $f(x) = kx$, where $k \in \mathbb R$, then $A = \phi$, So third option is wrong.

But I have no idea about (1) and (2), Please give me any hint . Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2., consider $f(x) = x \sin x$.

Suppose $a<b$ and $a,b \in A$. Then there are sequences $\alpha_n \to \infty, \beta_n \to \infty$ such that $f(\alpha_n) \to a, f(\beta_n) \to b$.

Choose $c\in (a,b)$ and let $a',b'$ be such that $a<a'<c<b'<b$ suppose $N$ is large enough so that $f(\alpha_n) <a'$, $f(\beta_n) > b'$ for $n \ge N$.

Using the intermediate value theorem, for all $n \ge N$ there is some $\gamma_n \in [\alpha_n,\beta_n]$ such that $f(\gamma_n) = c$.

Comment: if  $f(x) = x \sin x$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}  f(x_n) =  \lim_{n \to \infty} = x_n \sin (x_n) \to \infty$,  So $A = \phi$ which is compact .                                              In third statement , for any $c \in (a,b)  $, chose $ a < a ' < c < b' < b $, there exist $N$ such that $f(\alpha_n) < a' , f(\beta_n) > b' $, for $n \geq N$, how

Comment: No. The example for 2. shows that $A= \mathbb{R}$. That is, for any $y$ you can find some $x_n \to \infty$ such that $f(x_n) \to y$. you need to use the intermediate value theorem for this. To see this, sketch the graph and draw a horizontal line. Note that the line is crossed an infinite number of times.

Comment: If $f(\alpha_n) \to a$, then there must be some $N_1$ such that $f(\alpha_n) < a'$ for all $n \ge N_1$. Similarly there is some $N_2$ such that $f(\beta_n) > b'$ for all $n \ge N_2$. So, take $N = \max(N_1,N_2)$ and both will be satisfied.

Comment: I am trying to Show $A = \mathbb R$ for $f =x \sin x$ and thanks for giving your precious time.

Comment: Note that $f((2n\pm{1 \over 2}) \pi) = (2n\pm{1 \over 2}) \pi$. Pick some $c$ and $N$ such that $c \in [(2n-{1 \over 2}) \pi,(2n+{1 \over 2}) \pi]$ for all $n \ge N$. The intermediate value theorem shows that there is some $x_n \in [(2n-{1 \over 2}) \pi,(2n+{1 \over 2}) \pi]$ such that $f(x_n) = c$ and it is straightforward to show that $x_n \to \infty$.